# TMR1 is not incrementing PIC16f877a

Tags: microcontroller, c

I am developing an ultrasonic range finder.I am using PIC16f877a and the compiler MikroC.
I am using the CCP1 pin in PWM mode to generate an ultrasonic pulse. This pulse will be reflected back from an obstacle and received at the pin CCP2. Therefore, I am using CCP2 in capture mode.
The problem is TMR1H and TMR1L values remain zero throughout. i.e. my timer is not incrementing and I don't understand why is that. Also I am confused about the timer and registers. As far as my knowledge, TMR1 is to be used.
Here is the code:

```
unsigned int startTimerValueH;            //Global variable to store values of timer for calculation
unsigned int startTimerValueL;
unsigned int endTimerValueH;
unsigned int endTimerValueL;
unsigned int time_interval;
unsigned int display_value;
unsigned int distance;
unsigned int arr[4];


void Gen_UltraSound ()
{

     TRISB = 0x00;
     PORTB = 0;
     CMCON = 0x07;
     ADCON1 = 0x06;
     PWM1_init(40000);                  //initialize PWM module
     PWM1_set_duty(128);                //set the duty cycle to fifty percent

     T1CON.TMR1CS = 1;                  //external clock is used as clock source for timer1
     T1CON.T1SYNC = 0;                  //synchronizes the timer1 with external clock
     T1CON.T1CKPS1 = 0;
     T1CON.T1CKPS0 = 0;
     PIR1.TMR1IF = 0;                   //disables overflow
     T1CON.T1OSCEN = 0;                 //disables oscillator
     T1CON.TMR1ON = 1;                  //turns on the timer1

     startTimerValueH = TMR1H;          //stores the initial value of the timer as a binary number
     startTimerValueL = TMR1L;

     PWM1_start();                      //start generating the signal
     delay_ms(20);                      //delay during which the pulse is sent out to the speaker
     PWM1_stop();                       //stops the signal generator
}

 void displayDistance()
{
      TRISD=0x00;

      TRISB=0x00;
      PORTB=0x00;

      PORTD = 0x01;

}


void distanceMeasurer ()
{
       unsigned int remainder= 0;
       unsigned int quotient=0;
       unsigned int divisor=100;
       int i;

       distance = time_interval * 340;              //measures distance from the obstacle
       distance = distance / 2000;
       remainder = distance;

       for (i=0; i<3; ++i)
       {
            quotient = remainder/divisor;
            remainder = remainder%divisor;
            arr[i] = quotient;
            divisor = divisor/10;

       }

       displayDistance();                           //after measuring distance, display it

}


void main() {
     INTCON = 0b11000000;       //enables global interrrupts
     PIE2.CCP2IE = 1;           //enables peripheral interrupts so capture interrupt can occur

     CCP2CON.CCP2M3 = 0;        // sets CCP2 module to capture mode
     CCP2CON.CCP2M2 = 1;
     CCP2CON.CCP2M1 = 0;
     CCP2CON.CCP2M0 = 1;

     Gen_UltraSound();          //Ultra sound generator through PWM module
                 PIR1.CCP2IF = 1 ;   //for debugging purposes only
}

interrupt()
{
      TRISD = 0x00;
      if  (PIR1.CCP2IF == 1)
      {
           PIE2.CCP2IE = 0;                 //disables undesirable peripheral interrupts
           PIR1.CCP2IF = 0;                 //disables capture interrupts
           endTimerValueH = TMR1H;          //get timer value when echo received, in binary
           endTimerValueL = TMR1L;
           time_interval = endTimerValueL - startTimerValueL;  //time interval between transmission and reciept, in binary
           distanceMeasurer();                                 //measures the distance only when echo received
      }
}
```

EDIT: I have used an external clock 20MHz crystal. I wish to synchronize TMR1 with that. The crystal is at Pins OSC1 and OSC2

Answer (score 1):

One obvious issue is that you selected external clock for the timer, but haven't mentioned providing any external clock, nor does that seem to be what you want.

You need to read the datasheet, as you are confused about the timer 1 clock sources.  You now say you are providing a external clock, but then say this is a crystal between the OSC1 and OSC2 pins.  Those two statements are contradictory.  Again, READ THE DATASHEET, and read what I wrote above.

Comment: Editted the question